# Working remotely for European Company in Argentina - VISA required?

Tags: working-visas, eu, paperwork, argentine-citizens

I am an Argentinian national, and I would like to know if I need any type of VISA to work for an European Company remotely from Argentina and other Mercosur countries probably.

I have worked for this company in the headquarters in Europe before so I do have this country's ID (not expired) but I'm not a citizen of this Country.

Can I work for this company and be registered in Europe without any VISA as I won't be residing in Europe? Is there any official (government related) information I can use to support it's possible or not to do? Or should I declare myself self-employed in Argentina and work for this company without the need of registering in Europe?

Comment: *Visa* is not an acronym.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visas are not for work, they are for physical presence. If your physical presence includes employment, you'll need a special kind of visa, but if your employment doesn't require physical presence - you don't need any visa.

Just keep in mind that if you visit a foreign country and work for the European employer there - you **will** need a proper visa that allows employment. Any country.

But in your home country, Argentina, you can do whatever you want (assuming it is legal in Argentina). You don't need permission from any other country.

Answer (score 1):

I live in Brazil (hello, neighbour) and I work for a company based in the UK.

Here in Brazil, I had to create a small company in my name in order to receive money from abroad. An accountant helped me with the legal issues. I don't know how it is in Argentina, but maybe an accountant or a lawyer would help you.

Bonus tip: if you're going to **visit** your employer some day, you're probably going to need a **business visa** in that country. Don't confuse "business" and "work" at immigration if that day comes.